# input tex from variable

Tags: input

This `PR0101_Enunciado.tex` file is inside the folder `Ejercicios` and contains this line only :

```
Un enunciado de pregunta
```

Then, in another folder at the same level of `somefolder`, I have this `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\n}{PR0101}
\edef\fullfilename{../Ejercicios/{\n}\_Enunciado.tex}
\begin{document}
    \input{\fullfilename}
\end{document}
```

It is not working, how can i fix it?

Comment: remove the`{}` as there are no braces in the file name, and use `_` not `\_` for the underscore

Comment: `\newcommand\fullfilename{../Ejercicios/\n_Enunciado.tex}`

Comment: It works dont you want to post as an answer?

Comment: no need, Campa has answered already

Answer (score 2):

If I run

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\n}{PR0101}
\edef\fullfilename{../Ejercicios/{\n}\_Enunciado.tex}
\texttt{\meaning\fullfilename}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

The expansion of `\_` is much more complicated than you seem to think... let us forget that and use simply `_` instead of `\_`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\n}{PR0101}
\edef\fullfilename{../Ejercicios/{\n}_Enunciado.tex}
\texttt{\meaning\fullfilename}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Definitely better but... well, a pair of braces is stripped when TeX grabs undelimited arguments but *not*  during expansion.

Long story short: you want simply

```
\newcommand{\n}{PR0101}
\newcommand{\fullfilename}{../Ejercicios/\n_Enunciado.tex}
\input{\fullfilename}
```

or also just

```
\newcommand{\n}{PR0101}
\input{../Ejercicios/\n_Enunciado.tex}
```